# How do I get the auth code from the class?

Tags: php

Hi I have class and I am trying to get the auth code but when I do that it displays an error:

My code is this:

```
stdClass Object ( [emisor] => 76063822 [codigo] => ZTs3NjA2MzgyMjszOTsxNjAwNjk= [receptor] => 18598968 [fecha] => 2020-01-21 [vencimiento] => [total] => 20000 [dte] => 39 [temporal] => [emitido] => 160069 [pagado] => 2020-01-21 [medio] => webpay [datos] => {"cardDetail":{"cardNumber":"8011","cardExpirationDate":null},"detailOutput":{"authorizationCode":"011323","paymentTypeCode":"VD","responseCode":0,"sharesNumber":0,"amount":"20000","commerceCode":"597034994579","buyOrder":"76063822-39-160069"},"transactionDate":"2020-01-21T16:50:50.835-03:00"} [tienda] =>
```

And I do this:

```
$Cobro->datos->detailOutput->authorizationCode
```

and it shows "Trying to get property of non-object"

Why does it not work? because I think that it's correct, could you help me ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a JSON string within your object, so first you need to apply `json_decode()` and then to access the desired property:

```
$datos = json_decode($Cobro->datos);
print_r($datos);
echo $datos->detailOutput->authorizationCode;
```

produced `$datos` object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [cardDetail] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cardNumber] => 8011
            [cardExpirationDate] => 
        )

    [detailOutput] => stdClass Object
        (
            [authorizationCode] => 011323
            [paymentTypeCode] => VD
            [responseCode] => 0
            [sharesNumber] => 0
            [amount] => 20000
            [commerceCode] => 597034994579
            [buyOrder] => 76063822-39-160069
        )

    [transactionDate] => 2020-01-21T16:50:50.835-03:00
)
```

`echo` output:

```
011323
```